# Node.js convert bitmap string data to base64

Tags: node.js, bitmap

I have a server which receives bitmap string in endpoint. Something like that:

```
TkxSNdgbAAAgNgEBnA8AAAQDeAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgCcWZRTtVplbBt0w3PjNeMVToGHAbTADO4P
f/g7YfJnW1HeU0YSZlGmWTY4Vi8y8Bl1nCNHwG/Qu+GGwmLGGs07LxtnA2smOTd5wPhg8HjMH6OL
c8B8ZiZZmllLOmsyYw6yTCNcPyI+eMxMzxlPkWPi0NLF6cWpxc3M28y24WbxcB4b/hpR7DXgx8HG
h2smGzRLNEw0jvKa5/Hj4eE8R5vHYZZlHoYPivP5MTkyNZJrEotbmfOZWYYpHaQcuBz6M8RjkoxZ
y5JrjmtmLUO8452nD6gPuPzQSI8BxzdIviHcIeTF60GPJash6wFPIUcgazB8c/wPww+rgP3gTeFp
mPhY7E7E1sYuQm9zJvIkPJ0f/Bz4/NDmAMAvNdiH2AfJE84DzBb5B2OyZhxeJ/wD+YnHwE7AP/Lo
0hmTPZGN8cZhxmjmaaYefAs82g37CfHAMPNCPkobkiSmZSpzOGa+zmcYYB9ID9eE86C/GZ53szHw
mMjZwtnhdemmY0bn5AOzH7hczPAJ/BkMDobmnLnLecskwzHDM8MVwyQ2c4wbxw8H7pB86xlvMO5g
```

Is there anyway to convert this data to base64 string?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two steps:

1. Read URL into response buffer
2. Convert data to base 64

My example code

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

async function fetchpicture() {
    const response = await fetch('https://pixabay.com/photos/stadttheater-freiburg-main-page-5002861/');
    const picture = await response.buffer();
    const b64 = picture.toString('base64')
    return b64;
  }

fetchpicture().then(b64 => console.log(b64));
```

You will get

```
PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+CjwhLS1baWYgbHQgSUUgN10+IDxodG1sIGNsYXNzPSJuby1qcyBpZTYgb2xkaWUiIGxhbmc9ImVuLVVTIj4gPCFbZW5kaWZdLS0+CjwhLS1baWYgSUUgN10+ICAgIDxodG1sIGNsYXNzPSJuby1qcyBpZTcgb2xkaWUiIGxhbmc9ImVuLVVTIj4gPCFbZW5kaWZdLS0+CjwhLS1baWYg
```